# Going from Python list to numpy array while preserving type

Tags: python, numpy

I have a list of tuples in Python, in the format [(long, float, long)*].  I'd like to turn this into a numpy array.  However, when I do this using `np.array`, I get everything casted to float.  I'd like to preserve the types, keeping the integer values as integers.  How can I do this?

Answer (score 0):

You need a structured array:

```
numbers = np.array([(1, 2.3, 4)], dtype=[('a',int), ('b',float),('c',int)])
```